# How to use ConvexGeometry for a Object3D in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am following a threejs example: 
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_physics_convex_break.html

But I want to do the same for Object3D, instead of simple vertex. I have loaded one car model but cant seem to figure out what to input in ConvexBreaker.prepare
I have loaded the object using ObjLoader from js/loaders.

```
                pos.set( 0, 2, 16 );
                quat.set( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
                console.dir(carObj);
                var car = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(carObj), createMaterial( 0xF4AA21 ) );
                car.position.copy( pos );
                car.quaternion.copy( quat );
                convexBreaker.prepareBreakableObject( car, carMass, new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3(), true );
                createDebrisFromBreakableObject( car );
```

The console shows

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ConvexObjectBreak line 66
```

I understand that I have to obtain a geometry from the Obj and create a Mesh. But I cant figure out how.

Comment: First off, ConvexObjectBreak is not part of three.js, it's part of its examples. And its source states: "The Geometry must be convex You can create convex Geometries with THREE.ConvexGeometry. The BoxGeometry, SphereGeometry and other convex primitives can also be used.". As such, I would be really surprised if it worked with just any model. Your example is incomplete though, doesn't show how you obtain car or carObj and what they contain  ... try feeding carObj rather than car to the prepareBreakableObject method. It expects an Object3D which has a .geometry property.

Comment: Assuming I can create a convex geometry for the model, would I have to create it in blender or by code in threejs?